# Writing a System Call that Accesses a Kernel Variable

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I have my own kernel module which has a external integer variable:

```c
extern int i = 0;
```

I want to write a system call (in a separate file) that does the following to i:

```c
i = i + 1;
```

However, because i is declared in the kernel module file and not in the system call, it won't compile properly.  I know the problem doesn't lie elsewhere because the system call "works" fine when all it contains is a `printk` statement or something similarly self-contained.  How can I link the variable in the kernel module file to the system call file?

Comment: Usually kernel code is compiled as kernel module because one want to not modify kernel itself. But you need to modify kernel code in any case for *add system call*. So, it is simpler and better to add variable to the code, which processes system call.

Comment: http://linuxseekernel.blogspot.ie/2014/07/adding-system-call-in-x86-qemu.html will be helful.